# What is the difference between internal and external plugins on XFCE?

Tags: linux, debian, xfce, plugin

I want to make my own panel plugin on XFCE4 but I noticed that there are two types of plugins, Internal and External. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Xfce Panel Plugins How To](https://wiki.xfce.org/dev/howto/panel_plugins) page:

> The internal plugins are loadable modules, using the GModule
> interface. External plugins are separate programs that are embedded
> into the panel using the GtkPlug and GtkSocket mechanism.